# Pass queue object byval in VBA - Calling function object shouldn't be altered in called function

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to pass a queue to a function in VBA and have that function's actions not effect the queue object in the calling function.

For example in the code below queue starts with a size of 5000.  Then queue is passed to RemoveOneFromQueue and the size decreases to 4999.  I want queue in Main_Test to be unaffected by the actions in RemoveOneFromQueue.  I thought using ByVal in the function parameters would accomplish this but it doesn't seem to help.  Any ideas if this is possible?

I don't want to regenerate the queue each time as the real version will take too long to do that.

```
Sub Main_Test()
    Dim queue As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Set queue = GenerateQueue()
    Debug.Print queue.Count

    i = RemoveOneFromQueue(queue)
    Debug.Print queue.Count
End Sub

Function GenerateQueue() As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim queue As Object
    Set queue = CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue")
    For i = 1 To 5000
        queue.Enqueue i
    Next i
    Set GenerateQueue = queue
End Function

Function RemoveOneFromQueue(ByVal queue As Object) As Double
    Dim i As Long
    i = queue.Dequeue()
    RemoveOneFromQueue = i
End Function
```

Comment: If you don't want to remove the item from the queue then why use a queue ?  Or use Peek instead of Dequeue, but it's not clear what you really want to do here...

Comment: I'd start by renaming your variables because queue is the name of a class so can't be used as a variable.

Comment: This is because you are passing off a reference to a `Set` object. I think of these as similar to C/C++ pointers. You can pass off a new pointer but it is still pointing to the same memory block. This is not the same as passing off an assigned long, string or even variant since those are individual and independent assigned blocks of memory.

Comment: Well you could just generate 2 queues and pass one queue to the `RemoveOneeFromQueue` function. But I'm not sure that's what you want, but then again what you exactly want isn't clear either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VBA, objects themselves are not passed. 
You always pass a reference to the actual object, so it simply does not matter whether you put ByVal or ByRef in this scenario, since both the references will point to the same object. Calling members on that referenced object, will affect it everywhere.

However to fix your specific scenario you could instantiate a second queue and set it to queue.clone() since the Queue class implements the System.ICloneable interface so you're in luck... Try this:

```
Sub Main_Test()
    Dim queue As Object
    Set queue = GenerateQueue()
    Debug.Print queue.Count '5000
    RemoveOneFromQueue queue
    Debug.Print queue.Count '5000
End Sub

Sub GenerateQueue() As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim queue As Object
    Set queue = CreateObject("System.Collections.Queue")
    For i = 1 To 5000
        queue.Enqueue i
    Next i
    Set GenerateQueue = queue
End Function

Sub RemoveOneFromQueue(ByVal q As Object)
    Dim q2 As Object
    Set q2 = q.Clone()
    q2.Dequeue
    Debug.Print q2.Count '4999
End Sub
```

Keep in mind that q2 will not exist anymore after RemoveOneFromQueue finished executing.

However, it still matters whether you pass the reference itself ByVal or ByRef, as demonstrated in this example:

```
Sub MainTest()
   Dim queue as Object
   Set queue = GenerateQueue()
   Debug.Print queue.Count '5000
   ChangeByVal queue
   Debug.Print queue.Count '5000
   ChangeByRef queue
   Debug.Print queue.Count '4999
End Sub

Sub ChangeByVal(ByVal q as Object)
    Dim q2 As Object
    Set q2 = q.Clone()
    q2.Dequeue
    Debug.Print q2.Count '4999
    Set q = q2
End Sub


Sub ChangeByRef(ByRef q as Object)
    Dim q2 As Object
    Set q2 = q.Clone()
    q2.Dequeue
    Debug.Print q2.Count '4999
    Set q = q2
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect!  Even better using clone() is showing no speed loss.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's impossible ;(

VBA handles COM Object aways as reference.

Now you must check what is faster reenqueuing just after you dequeue, or make a copy of it, or use some native VBA array or something instead of Collection Object, as it can be passed ByVal (Which actually do a copy of the object)

```
Function RemoveOneFromQueue(ByVal queue As Object) As Double
    Dim i As Long
    i = queue.Dequeue()
    RemoveOneFromQueue = i
    queue.Enqueue i
End Function
```